# Return value of the generator method throw

Tags: python, generator, return-value, yield, throw

The help of throw says:

throw(...) method of builtins.generator instance
throw(typ[,val[,tb]]) -> raise exception in generator,
return next yielded value or raise StopIteration

"return next yielded value" this is my problem!

Let's have a look at this example:

```
def gen():
    counter = 1
    while True:
        try:
            yield counter
            counter += 1
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception and tpye: ", e, type(e))
            

x = gen()
print("Result of first next call: ", next(x))
res = x.throw(ValueError("Whatever!"))
print("result of throw call: ", res)
print("Result of first next call: ", next(x))
```

The output looks like this:

```
Result of first next call:  1
Exception and tpye:  Whatever! <class 'ValueError'>
result of throw call:  1
Result of first next call:  2
```

Shouldn't the return value of throw be 2 instead of one? The help file says "return NEXT yielded value2" not "return again previously yielded value"

I am afraid that I got something completely wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `gen.throw(...)`, the exception is raised at the `yield` statement.

While you catch it, the following incrementation of counter is not executed. You can move it into a `finally:`-clause to ensure that no matter what, you always increment `counter`:

```
def gen():
    counter = 1
    while True:
        try:
            yield counter
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception and type: ", e, type(e))
        finally:
            counter += 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much. My problem is not to get this example running but to understand the - to my mind - strange behaviour of the return. It is not doing what the help file says. Apparantly throw returns the most recently yielded value?

Comment: No, it returns the next yielded value. But since you don't increment `counter` in your code when the exception is thrown, it will again yield the same alue.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I got it. It makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Put the counter before the yield:

```
counter += 1
yield counter
```

Otherwise, the first yield will be with `counter==1`.